# How to apply partial functions to list of tuples

Tags: haskell

The title of this question might sound misleading, but I wasnt sure how else to explain what I'm trying to do.

I'm experimenting with non-deterministic data structures. I'm trying to produce all possible combinations of a set of partially apply operators and a list of tuples:

```
-- test.hs
makeTupleList :: (Int, Int) -> [(Int, Int)] 
makeTupleList (a, b) = ZipList [(+2), (-2)] <*> ZipList [a, b]
```

I want `makeTupleList` to return something like:

```
[(a + 2, b + 2), (a + 2, b - 2), (a - 2, b + 2), (a - 2, b - 2)]
```

But I'm clearly doing something wrong because I keep getting this error:

```
Couldn't match type `ZipList' with `[]'
```

How do I get my desired result?

Comment: What's prompting you to use `ZipList` at all?

Comment: By the way, a terminology thing: usually these are called "partially applied functions", not "partial functions", and "partial functions" is reserved for functions which may throw an error or loop forever.

Answer (score 4):

There's a mismatch between the type you declared and the type the function actually has.

Let's just check the body of the function

```
*> :t \(a, b) -> ZipList [(+2), (-2)] <*> ZipList [a, b]
\(a, b) -> ZipList [(+2), (-2)] <*> ZipList [a, b]
  :: (Num (b -> b), Num b) => (b, b) -> ZipList b
```

Eep! That's not good at all.

So let's fix the error. The first error is that `-2` trips you up, because it parses as negative two, not an operator section.

You can see that by typechecking just that fragment:

```
*> :t (-2)
(-2) :: Num a => a
```

Ok, so we'll change it to an explicit lambda, and get closer:

```
*> :t \(a, b) -> ZipList [(+2), (\x -> x - 2)] <*> ZipList [a, b]
\(a, b) -> ZipList [(+2), (\x -> x - 2)] <*> ZipList [a, b]
  :: Num b => (b, b) -> ZipList b
```

Now we see the conceptual error (you can see even more if you test it). We're just getting back `[a+2,b-2]`. That's what ziplist *does* -- "zips" the lists together. It doesn't take the cross product.

So now we see we're on the completely wrong track.

When we want to take a "producty" combination, I find the most natural way is to use a list comprehension. So let's just do that instead.

```
makeTupleList (a,b) = let funs = [(+2),(\x->x-2)]
                      in [(f a, g b) | f <- funs, g <- funs]
```

And that seems to do it.

```
*> makeTupleList (10,20)
[(12,22),(12,18),(8,22),(8,18)]
```

Answer (score 4):

I would drop the ZipList:

```
makeTupleList :: (Int, Int) -> [(Int, Int )]
makeTupleList (a,b) = (,) <$> aList <*> bList
 where
  functionList :: [Int -> Int]
  functionList = [flip (-) 2  ,(+ 2) ]
  aList :: [Int]
  aList = functionList <*> [a]
  bList = functionList <*> [b]
```

Yielding:

```
 λ> makeTupleList (1,1)
 [(-1,-1),(-1,3),(3,-1),(3,3)]
```

ZipList is for not generating permutations out of an applicative action.

Comment: `flip (-) 2` is `subtract 2`.

Comment: Is there a way to curry the `(-)` function without using `flip` or something weird like `(+(-2))`

Comment: The  lambda wrapper works and is probably the clearest.